# “Canary” as a masculine

Tags: grammar, personal-pronouns

“I bought ***him*** in Palermo”, says the American lady from “A canary for one” by Ernest Hemingway. Why does she use a masculine pronoun talking about the canary?

Maybe it is coherent with using “she” for the ship?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Animals have an inherent sex, male or female. It is common to use "he" or "she" of animals when their sex is known. This is particularly true of pets.

In the case of a canary, only the male bird will sing (the female chirps but doesn't sing in the same way that the male will). If the American lady has a singing canary, she knows it is a male bird. If she had a non-singing canary she would likely use "she"

As I said, if the animal is a pet, it is very common to use he or she. Farm animals and wild animals are sometimes called he/she, and sometimes they are called "it". Use a gendered pronoun when you want to empathise with the animal.